# Using Puppeteer to attempt login and send screenshot (node.js)

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, discord.js, puppeteer

Hello I am having a bit of a hard time trying to get the login(submit) to happen. I see puppeteer is able to write my username and password but failing to login.

Here is my code I don't think I'm getting the proper element back maybe??

```
testblockscreenshot: async function (){
  debugger;
  console.log("Getting screenshot...");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'false' },{devtools: true});  
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const options = {
    path: 'images/website.png',
    fullpage: true,
    omitBackground: true
  }  
  const options2 = {
    path: 'images/website2.png',
    fullpage: true,
    omitBackground: true
  } 
  const options3 = {
    path: 'images/website3.png',
    fullpage: true,
    omitBackground: true
  } 
  await page.goto('https://hyblockcapital.com/login');
  //await page.click('cookieConsent');
  await page.type('[name="Email"]', 'obfuscated');
  await page.type('[name="Password"]', 'obfuscated');
  console.log('Take Screenshot1...');
  await page.screenshot(options);
  console.log('Take Screenshot2...');
  await page.screenshot(options2);
   console.log("Wait for Nav...");
  await page.waitForSelector('[type="submit"]');
  const submitButton = await page.$('button[type="submit"]');
  if (submitButton) {
    const isButtonDisabled = await submitButton.evaluate((btn) => btn.disabled);
    if (!isButtonDisabled) {
      await submitButton.click();
      console.log("Lets attempt to click the button");
    } else {
      console.log('The submit button is disabled and cannot be clicked.');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Submit button not found.');
  }
  await delay(120000); // Wait for 2000 milliseconds (2 min)
  await page.screenshot(options3);
  await page.goto('https://hyblockcapital.com/liquidationlevel');
  await page.screenshot(options4);
  await page.screenshot(options5);
  await browser.close();
}
};
```

This is the site I am trying to get screenshots of https://hyblockcapital.com/login

This is node.js but that of discord.js. I have tried multiple ways but cant get it to submit. The third screenshot does come back blank so maybe its attempting login. Most times it will time out.

return new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(errorMessage);
^

TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
at LifecycleWatcher._LifecycleWatcher_createTimeoutPromise

here is the element as so

```
button type="submit" class="submit_btn width_100 m_t_35 btn_color 
btn_cls">Login</button
```

I am expecting that I should get passed the login screen to the next page so I can attempt to take a screenshot of what is displaying.

Is there anyway to tell if maybe the site just wont let headless automation login? Not really sure what to do to be fair now.

Comment: Why are you using `Promise.all` in this case? I would assume that you would want the ClickEvent to be finished before taking a screenshot? I would even advice adding https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector to wait for the full page load and then take a screenshot just to be sure.

Comment: Pretty much tried everything I can lol. I updated code but still that thrid screenshot is coming back with username and password blank im not sure if its slowly navigating and not allowing it or what. Any way I could add logging to what puppeteer is doing?

Comment: I will update my post with new changes

Comment: Thanks for the extra info that makes it more clear have you tried using a debugger or placing console logs to see what parts it is hitting from the if statement? I see that you are not using a `await delay` function which i assume just waits a couple of seconds. I think a better way is to find an element that is present on the page after the login page and use a `waitForSelector` on that specific element to check if it is there this makes it so if it loads quickly you do not have to wait for the full delay. Furthermore to debug you can of course also run it in non headless and see what happens